# Is there a way to do fopen with relative path with gdb?

Tags: c, gcc, path, gdb, filepath

I am trying to do fopen() with relative path.
The code is a simple one:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main (void){

    char filename[FILENAME_MAX]="test.txt";
    FILE *fin;
    if ((fin=fopen(filename,"r"))==NULL)
    {
        printf("File not found.");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("opened!");
    }
    
    return 0;

}
```

I tried 2 methods:

1. compiling the code with gcc and then running it with ./a
2. using the gdb build & run on vscode, the settings are exactly from https://medium.com/@GorvGoyl/run-debug-intellisense-c-c-in-vscode-within-5-minutes-3ed956e059d6

I have tried changing filename into several things and here are the result:

`char filename[FILENAME_MAX]="test.txt";`

gcc: opened!

gdb: file not found

`char filename[FILENAME_MAX]=".\\test.txt";`

gcc: opened!

gdb: file not found

`char filename[FILENAME_MAX]="C:\\fullfolderpath\\test.txt";`

gcc: opened!

gdb: opened!

Is there a way to open the txt file with relative path while using gdb? the files will be stored on the same directory as the source code, and the compiled program.

Comment: You could try to figure out the working directory so you know what relative paths are relative from. Use [`getcwd`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getcwd.html) in your program to check it.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/absolute

Comment: Oh and please tag only the language you're actually program in. C and C++ are two very different languages.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I edited the post and will try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use at least [perror(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html) when [fopen(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html) fails, and of course **read the documentation** of these functions.

So code:

```
if ((fin=fopen(filename,"r"))==NULL)
{
    perror(filename);
    printf("File not found.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

### read documentation of [printf(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) and of [exit(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exit.3.html) before using them.

Of course, read also the documentation of [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) and of [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/).

I recommend compiling your `foo.c` with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g foo.c -o foo`

On Linux, consider also using [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) (read of course [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)...) to understand the behavior of your program.

If you use some other operating system or compiler **read the documentation of your compiler and of your operating system**. For Windows, refer to the [WinAPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API).